# Regex not within <script> tags

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Need help with some regex. I'd like to match everything within a given string of HTML that matches the pattern `\*[a-z0-9\_]+\*` that does not fall in between `<script>` start and end tags. I know this has something to do with lookarounds, but I haven't a clue how to get there.

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: Ruby, but I'm trying to do it in pure regex.

Comment: May this work... it's just an idea: [^s][^c][^r][^i][^p][^t]\*[a-z0-9\_]+\*

Comment: Easy way - strip out script first.

Comment: That wouldn't work at all? That would match anything that has 6 characters that don't spell script before a match.

Comment: That changes the question entirely, I'm not trying to change the content.

Comment: <!-- <script> --> not_really_here_01 <!-- </script> --> .....

Comment: What question? you think you can actually parse html with regular expressions?

Comment: MAYBE not duplicate, since we are specifically addressing the lookaround regex extension which might make a ruby regex enough for this particular use, barring the comment abuse example I cited above...

Comment: @TetsujinnoOni [Please stop linking to the “Zalgo” / anti-Cthulhu regex rant](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261561/471272).  It doesn’t help anybody.  Thank you.

Comment: @tchrist noted. Possibly more constructively related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Answer (score 2):

Using regex lookaround. You can use:

```
(?!<script>)\*[a-z0-9\_]+\*(?!</script>)
```

That will match your regex only if it is not preceded and postceded by script

[image]

Comment: Right... but what if there's a lot of javascript within the script tags?

Comment: @kdeisz have you tried that? It is what you asked for, btw could you update the question with some sample data I'd like to help you with accuracy

Comment: @kdeisz what this regex does is to match the content that don't fall inside <script>

Comment: This regex does not work if you have something like `<script type='text/javascript'>var a = *abc*;</script>`

Comment: @kdeisz you just have to remove the ">" from the first <script>. Since you haven't provided a sample I based on the common example, I'd be glad to help you accurately but need sample data.

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer) No. 1 rule, don't use regex to parse html.

---

You have to match script tags to avoid them.
The answer is in group 1, check for length, then its valid.

```
    # <script>.*?</script>|(\*[a-z0-9_]+\*)

    <script> .*? </script>
 |  
    ( \* [a-z0-9_]+ \* )               # (1)
```